# How to reload the Jtable contents from the database when i update a row in gui?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i have set value to the database by directly typing into the Jtable cell using TableModelListener.But i'm unable to reload the data in the Jtable after updation.

```java
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
    String updateq = "update M_department set " + getColumnName(column) + "='" 
            + value.toString() + "' where code='" + getValueAt(row, 0) + "'";
    System.out.println(updateq);
    try {
        stmt.executeUpdate(updateq);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error" + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should call super.SetValueAt(). If you want to relod data from database you will have to re-initialize the model, lot depends on how you have implemented the model.